# File sharing PHP or RoR script

Tags: sharing

I am looking for a file sharing script (PHP or Ruby on Rails) that:

- has user management
- admin can set a hierarchy of directories/folders
- user can upload file to directory
- user can see other files and download them

Someting similar to [iDocScript](http://www.idocscript.com/).

Comment: Do you care about pricing or license?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out ownCloud, I've been using it for quite some time now and it's great. It meets your requirements of,

- Very powerful Admin Dashboard
- User Management
- Users can upload their own files and/or folders
- Users can share their own files and/or folders with other users and/or the world (through the use of links)

## [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) ([Open Source](https://github.com/owncloud))

> ownCloud gives you web services under your control. It is a
>   self-hosted open source platform with file sync & sharing at its core
>   and available clients for desktop and mobile. The web frontend has
>   apps for Pictures, Calendar, Contacts, News/RSS, Bookmarks, Notes,
>   Music and much more via an open app platform! ownCloud Server can be
>   installed on Windows and Linux operating systems, and is available via
>   packages, sources, or a one file php installer.
>
> [image: OwnCloud UI]